# react-native-torch is not working properly

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to use [react-native-torch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch) with react native. I took this [code](https://github.com/ludo/TorchDemo/blob/master/index.android.js) and put it into my project. I have also installed react-native-torch with `npm install --save react-native-torch`. My App.js looks like this (sorry for using code snippet, I wasn't able to achieve propriate formating with `this formating`):

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
   AppRegistry,
   Button,
   NativeModules,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View
 } from 'react-native';
 import Torch from 'react-native-torch';
 
 export default class TorchDemo extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
 
     this.state = {
       isTorchOn: false,
     };
   }
 
   _handlePress() {
     const { isTorchOn } = this.state;
     Torch.switchState(!isTorchOn);
     this.setState({ isTorchOn: !isTorchOn });
   }
 
   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text style={styles.welcome}>
           RCTTorch Demo
         </Text>
         <Button
           onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}
           title="Toggle Torch"
         />
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
   },
   welcome: {
     fontSize: 20,
     textAlign: 'center',
     margin: 10,
   },
   instructions: {
     textAlign: 'center',
     color: '#333333',
     marginBottom: 5,
   },
 });
 
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('TorchDemo', () => TorchDemo);
```

Everything runs as it should, but when I tap the toogle torch button, I am getting this warning and the flashlight will not turn on:

[image: expo error]

I have tried many forms of their demo codes, but the problem was always with `Torch.switchState`.
Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? 
Thank you very much for any help. 
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Did you try building the app again as this module requires linking? If not, you need to run the React Native app again.

For android run: `npx react-native run-android`

For ios run: `npx react-native run-ios`

Comment: No I didn't. What command does that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please provide further details? I would love to know what do you mean by building app again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a managed workflow, it won't work through Expo Go. You need to use a development client for native code to work. Create it with EAS.

1. Install the **expo-dev-client** library
   `expo install expo-dev-client`
2. Create an eas.json `eas build:configure`
3. Build client and install on device/emulator `eas build -p android --profile development`
4. Use `expo start --dev-client` instead of 'expo start'

Docs: https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/